# How can i package the Visual Studio 2010 runtime with my .exe and .dll file?

Tags: visual-studio

As sort of a hello world attempt, I am compiling a simple EXE that dynamically loads a DLL (which I have also written) using only C++ files, building with Visual Studio 2010. However, when running on a new machine, an error appears that the VS2010 runtime is not present.

Is there a way to package the runtime in my application or DLL so this doesn't occur? Without using an installer program.

Alternatively, is there a way to exclude requiring the runtime at all?

(I am using Visual Studio 2010, but this could really be of interest for all versions)

Comment: No, Visual Studio has a different runtime for every version of the compiler.

Comment: But those are different versions of the _C++_ runtime. (MSVCPP)

Comment: But I want a specific version of it. I don't want every C++ runtime.

Comment: Add a Setup project to your solution.